# GUI Label shows on screen when object is out of view?

Tags: c#, unity

I have GUI Labels over NPCs in my game, and the labels display their name above their head. But when I walk away and go somewhere else, their names stay on screen like it's mirrored or something?

Here's what I'm talking about:

This is how it looks normally

[image: This is what it looks like on screen normally]

This is what happens when I walk out of view.

[image: This is what it looks like when I walk out of view]

**The Code:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NPC : MonoBehaviour {

private float left;
private float top;
public float leftModifier;
public float topModifier;

private Vector3 NPCScreenPosition;

//FIX THE MIRRORING ISSUE

void Start () {

}

void Update () {
    Vector3 NPCNameWorldPosition = (transform.position + new Vector3(0.0f, transform.lossyScale.y, 0.0f));
    NPCScreenPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(NPCNameWorldPosition);
    left = NPCScreenPosition.x + leftModifier;
    top = Screen.height - (NPCScreenPosition.y + topModifier);
}

void OnGUI() {
    GUI.Label(new Rect(left, top, 150, 25), gameObject.name.ToString());
  }
}
```

Comment: If the character can't be seen by the camera, hide his character label? Also please don't add tags to the question title (eg. [Unity])

Comment: Not sure if this would work but try http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-isVisible.html

Answer (score 2):

i recently resolved a similar issue by doing as bummzack suggested in his comment.  the gui element is going to try and draw the nameplate on a 2d plane in front of the camera regardless of the direction its facing.  you need to stop it manually

```
void Update () {

    Vector2 temp = cam.WorldToViewportPoint( target.position + offset );

    // check if camera is facing the target
    float angle = 60;  // my cameras view angle

    if ( Vector3.Angle( cam.transform.forward, transform.position - cam.transform.position) < angle ){

        transform.position = temp;
        guiText.text = "WORKING";
        guiText.color = Color.green;

    }

}
```

Comment: This will work. However using <some_renderer>.IsVisible seems like a simpler solution. Probably cheaper too.